# Generating non-overlapping spheres, python

Tags: python, algorithm, package

Does any of you know, apart from the (to-me) very complicated to install [Yade](https://yade-dem.org/doc/user.html) package, a package that allows for easily generating an arbitrary ammount non-overlapping spheres inside a parallelepiped ?

If not, could you direct me to a source explaining how to efficienctly implement such an algorithm ?

Any input appreciated

Comment: For an algorithm see http://www.academia.edu/481430/A_geometric_algorithm_based_on_tetrahedral_meshes_to_generate_a_dense_polydisperse_sphere_packing.

Comment: and I would recommend to add `random` rag

Answer (score 1):

More often people looking for to non-overlapping circles generation, which could be extended to spheres. It is discussed on math.stackexchange, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/efficient-way-to-generate-random-points-with-a-predefined-lower-bound-on-their-p and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69649/generate-nonoverlapping-random-circles, I would like to point out to another potential solution which involves quasi-random numbers. For quasi-random Sobol sequences there is a statement which says that there is minimum positive distance between points which amounts to 0.5*sqrt(d)/N, where d is dimension of the problem, and N is number of points sampled in hypercube. Paper from the man himself http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378475406002382